# Sending Email via SSL settings

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I am able to send email with the following code if I send without enabling SSL. When I enable SSL, I have to change the credentials such as port and outgoing server. Have checked the credentials multiple times and they are correct and also confirmed the credentials with my hosting company. Am I missing any steps which is preventing me from sending out the mail via SSL. Please advice thanks.

```
//Sending without SSL which works
public static string error;
public static void Send()
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.mywebsite.com"); 

        mail.From = new MailAddress("management@mywebsite.com");
        mail.To.Add("report@mywebsite.com");

        mail.Subject = "Inventory Status/ Update";
        mail.Body = Connection.emailUpdate;

        SmtpServer.Port = 26;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("management@mywebsite.com", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 10000;
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.ToString();
    }
}

//Sending with SSL which fails
public static string error;
public static void Send()
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("eu2.01domain.net");//Change in outgoing server 

        mail.From = new MailAddress("management@mywebsite.com");
        mail.To.Add("report@mywebsite.com");

        mail.Subject = "Inventory Status/ Update";
        mail.Body = Connection.emailUpdate;

        SmtpServer.Port = 465; //Change in port
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("management@mywebsite.com", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true; //SSL enabled

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 10000;
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also post the exception details (exclude/obscure sensitive info)

Comment: what exception is thrown? does the event viewer show anything? Also, you don't need to use `.ToString()` on an `Exception` variable, since it is already in string format.

Comment: There is no exception. The screen just freezes till I stop the process. When I stop the process, all I get is a message saying the thread has stopped. I tried to swap the port to 26 with SSL enabled and it works then. But that is not the recommended port for SSL. According to host company, should use 465.

Comment: could it be your firewall settings? Does your event viewer say anything under the application, security or system views?

Comment: Temporarily disabled firewall and still same results.

Comment: and the event viewer? is anything showing up there? honestly, from your description, the problem seems to be network related, not code related. Something is blocking the communication, and that is causing the application to hang.